# Understanding a retained fragment as a task holder

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just took a look at the two following examples of the fragment as a task holder approach:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.java
- http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Why did they need `UiFragment` in the first example? Messages from the task holder fragment can be sent to its activity directly as it's done in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did they need `UiFragment` in the first example?

They did not **need** that `Fragment`.

It's just a simple example, seems like they chose to use a `Fragment` for the content instead of calling `setContentView()` on the `Activity`.

There are two `Fragment`s basically in the Google example:

- A `Fragment` for the UI
- A worker `Fragment` to retain the state of a `Thread` through the re-creation of the `Activity` (in case of an orientation change for example).

They could have just ditch the UI `Fragment` and call `setContentView()` on the `Activity` and it wouldn't make a difference. The point of the example is the worker `Fragment`.